# lib32asound : Dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm getting this error when I try to install `teamviewer` , the error is

```
Dependency is not satisfiable lib32asound2
```

I already tired `sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386` but no good.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was fixed installing 32 bit version of teamviewer. Apparently x64 package doesn't work on Ubuntu x64.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly install `teamviewer`, you've to install the `libc6-i386` package.

You can install it by,

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Comment: there's no such package in Saucy.

Comment: Its There. Check: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libc6-i386

Comment: I installed the package but I am still getting the dependency error.

Comment: Doesn't helped me.

Comment: refer to @mannos answer

Comment: I get `libc6-i386 is already the newest version.` (14.04) -- guess I'll have to download the x86 package from TeamViewer